# sql server changing compatibility level from 100 to 120

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

Change compatibility from 100 to 120

we have migrated few databases from SQL server 2008 to SQL server2014  Standard Edition but Compatibility level was not changed and some more information those databases are configured with mirroring, is there any impact on application if I change compatibility level from 100 to 120? I have read that by changing the compatibility level does not have any performance issues apart from improvement in the performance we can  have new feature which are in SQL server 2014 and please correct me if I am wrong finally I have question any impact on mirroring or application Functionality

Comment: Probably better asked on the DBA site, but even there it may be felt to be too broad. Most of our sites, we tend to prefer to see *one* question asked in the question.

Comment: *"I have read that by changing the compatibility level does not have any performance issues apart from improvement in the performance"* Really? 2014 introduced a brand new cardinality estimator, which can have **major** performance changes, good and bad (although most have the bad, due to possibly poorly written queries).

Answer (score 2):

> I have read that by changing the compatibility level does not have any
>   performance issues apart from improvement

Where did you read it? Of course there can be performance degradation, as in `2014` new `cardinality estimator` was introduced. So some of your `query plans` can change from optimal to suboptimal. That's why `compatibility level 100` is still maintained, by setting it you tell your server to use the `old cardinality estimator` for all your database queries.

In case there are only few queries that became slower, you can leave `compatibility level 120` and use `9481` `query trace flag` for those queries as described here: [Enable plan-affecting SQL Server query optimizer behavior that can be controlled by different trace flags on a specific-query level](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2801413/enable-plan-affecting-sql-server-query-optimizer-behavior-that-can-be)